# Preciso de ajuda para entender este codigo

Tags: python, lógica

Estou iniciando em python assistindo video aulas no youtube,o seguinte exercicio foi passado:

```
if 10 <= saque <= 600:
    notas_cem = saque // 100
    saque = saque % 100
```

NÃO ENTENDI ESTAS PARTES,porque a variavel "notas_cem"é atribuida ao saque dividido por 100?e porque o saque é igual ao resto dessa divisão?

O programa não deve se preocupar com a quantidade de notas existentes na
máquina.

> Exemplo 1: Para sacar a quantia de 256 reais, o programa fornece duas
> notas de 100, uma nota de 50, uma nota de 5 e uma nota de 1;
>
> Exemplo 2: Para sacar a quantia de 399 reais, o programa fornece três
> notas de 100, uma nota de 50, quatro notas de 10, uma nota de 5 e
> quatro notas de 1.

```
saque = int(input("Digite o valor do saque: "))

if 10 <= saque <= 600:
    notas_cem = saque // 100
    saque = saque % 100

    notas_cinquenta = saque // 50
    saque = saque % 50

    notas_dez = saque // 10
    saque = saque % 10 

    notas_cinco = saque // 5
    saque = saque % 5

    notas_um = saque // 1

    if notas_cem > 0:
        print(notas_cem, "notas de R$ 100")
    if notas_cinquenta > 0:
        print(notas_cinquenta, "notas de R$ 50")
    if notas_dez > 0:
        print(notas_dez, "notas de R$ 10")
    if notas_cinco > 0:
        print(notas_cinco, "notas de R$ 5")
    if notas_um > 0:
        print(notas_um, "notas de R$ 1")
              
else:
    print("Nao é possivel fazer o saque")
```

Answer (score 1):

> *porque a variavel "notas_cem"é atribuida ao saque dividido por 100?e porque o saque é igual ao resto dessa divisão?*

Bom, vamos supor que o valor do saque seja 256 reais. Como você faz para saber quantas notas de 100 serão necessárias? Dividindo por 100.

E no caso foi usado o operador de divisão inteira (`//`), assim o resultado já é arredondado. No caso, 256 dividido por 100 dá 2 (portanto, preciso de 2 notas de 100).

Mas 2 notas de 100 dá um total de 200, só que o valor do saque é 256. Ou seja, ainda preciso saber a quantidade das outras notas. Então pego o valor do saque (no nosso exemplo, 256) e calculo o resto da divisão por 100. Isso resulta em 56, que é o valor que falta se descontarmos as notas de 100.

Depois o algoritmo continua, usando o mesmo raciocínio com as demais notas: repare que ele faz o mesmo com 50, 10, 5 e 1 - se bem que com notas de 1 é desnecessário, pois dividir por 1 não muda nada (a não ser que o valor tivesse também os centavos, mas não parece ser o caso).

No final temos a quantidade de cada uma das notas.

E o algoritmo também funciona se o valor for menor que 100. Por exemplo, se for um saque de 90, a divisão por 100 dá zero (pois não precisa de nenhuma nota de 100), e o resto da divisão por 100 dá 90 (e aí prossegue com as notas de 50, etc).

Aproveitando, [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/467069/112052) tem outras opções diferentes para este mesmo algoritmo.