# JavaScript - Função que chegue a um valor usando moedas

Tags: javascript, lógica

Crie uma função que recebe um número entre 5 a 255 e também as moedas: "1, 5, 7, 9 e 11" o objetivo é chegar ao número escolhido entre 5 a 255 usando a menor quantidade de moedas possiveis.

ex: se o número for 20 o menor número de moedas sera 2 ('11' e '9').

Uma das dificuldades que tive foi quando os valores do meu array acabam eu não consigo fazer com que a função volte a percorrer o array de novo.

Desde agradeço a todo!!!

```js
const number = 20;
const values = [11, 9, 7, 5, 1];
const coins = [];
let total = 0;
let coinsQuantity = 0;


function totalCoins(number) {
  if(total !== number) {
    for(let value of values) {
      if(value === number && total !== number) {
        coins.push(value);
        coinsQuantity = coinsQuantity + 1;
        total = coins[0];
        return console.log(`
          Total de moedas ${coins.length}
          Moedas usadas ${coins.join(' - ')}
        `)
      }
      else if(value < number && total < number) {
        coins.push(value);
        coinsQuantity = coinsQuantity + 1
        total = coins.reduce((a, b) => {
          return a + b
        })
      }
      else if(total === number) {
        return console.log(`
          Total de moedas ${coins.length}
          Moedas usadas ${coins.join(' - ')}
        `)
      }
    }
  }
}

totalCoins(number);
```

Comment: Não é em JavaScript mas a ideia geral do algoritmo é a mesma: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/467069/112052

Answer (score -3):

Use o while nesse caso. Segue algo parecido que fiz, usando outras funções também para uma cashMachine. Adapte à sua necessidade. Uma dica de ouro, se estiver estudando nessas escolas que paga quando começa a trabalhar, está pedindo ajuda no lugar errado.

```
const cashMachine = (saque, salarioFixo, vendas) => {
    let salarioComVendas = calculateSalary(salarioFixo, vendas);
    let saldoConta = parseInt(salarioComVendas - saque);
    let valorDoSaque = saque;
    let duzentos = 0;
    let cem = 0
    let cinquenta = 0
    let vinte = 0
    let dez = 0
    let cinco = 0
    let dois = 0

    while(valorDoSaque >= 200) {
        valorDoSaque -= 200;
        duzentos += 1;
    }
    while (valorDoSaque >= 100 && valorDoSaque <= 200) {
        valorDoSaque -= 100;
        cem += 1;
    }
    while (valorDoSaque >= 50 && valorDoSaque <= 100) {
        valorDoSaque -= 50;
        cinquenta += 1;
    }
    while (valorDoSaque >= 20 && valorDoSaque <= 50) {
        valorDoSaque -= 20;
        vinte += 1;
    }
    while (valorDoSaque >= 10 && valorDoSaque <= 20) {
        valorDoSaque -= 10;
        dez += 1;
    }
    while (valorDoSaque >= 7 && valorDoSaque <= 10) {
        valorDoSaque -= 5;
        cinco += 1;
    }
    while (valorDoSaque >= 2 && valorDoSaque <= 6) {
        if (valorDoSaque === 5) {
            valorDoSaque -= 5;
            cinco += 1;
        }
        else {
            valorDoSaque -= 2;
            dois += 1;
        }
    }
    if  (saque < 2){
        return 'Notas disponíveis: R$ 2,00 R$ 5,00 R$ 10,00 R$ 20,00 R$ 50,00 R$ 100,00 R$ 200,00.';
    }
    return {
        Saldo_Atual:  saldoConta+',00',
        Notas_de_Duzentos: duzentos,
        Notas_de_Cem: cem,
        Notas_de_Cinquenta: cinquenta,
        Notas_de_Vinte: vinte,
        Notas_de_Dez: dez,
        Notas_de_Cinco: cinco,
        Notas_de_Dois: dois
    };
}
```