# Alguém poderia me explicar a lógica por trás desse código?

Tags: python, lógica

estou aprendendo a programar agora e acho que tenho ido até bem, decidi começar com python lendo o livro "Introdução a Programação com Python", de Nilo Ney, por indicação de um amigo e tenho entendido bastante, mas tem um código nesse livro que eu não consigo entender, e eu realmente não gosto de avançar sem entender tudo de cada parte, alguém poderia me ajudar?

o código é esse:

```
valor=int(input("Digite o valor a pagar:"))
cédulas=0
atual=50
apagar=valor
while True:
    if atual<=apagar:
        apagar-=atual
        cédulas+=1
    else:
        print("%d cédula(s) de R$%d" % (cédulas, atual))
        if apagar == 0:
            break
        if atual == 50:
            atual = 20
        elif atual == 20:
            atual = 10
        elif atual == 10:
            atual = 5
        elif atual == 5:
            atual = 1
        cédulas = 0
```

Comment: Como já disseram, é um algoritmo de "caixa eletrônico", pra ver quais notas precisa pra determinado valor. Vale lembrar que tem formas melhores de fazer: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/467069/112052

Answer (score -4, accepted):

O código em questão ele fala quantas cédulas são precisas para pagar uma determinada e de quantas dessas cédulas eu preciso para pagar tendo como padrão/base as notas de 50, 20, 10, 5, 1 e 0. Então a execução acredita que **se/if** o valor atual que le já deixa como 50 e diminui esse valor até ser 0. Exemplo: 100 -> 50 - 50 = 1 cédula de 50, aí ele passa novamente se if e 50 - 50 = 2 cédulas de 50. Caso a cedula tenha outros valores ela entra no **senão/else** e segue a mesma lógica do que lhe expliquei, porém com outros valores.

Comment: eu entendi muito bem, obrigado

Answer (score -1):

Esse código tem como objetivo selecionar as notas que serão usadas para pagar um determinado valor.
Pro exemplo, para pagar o valor de R$ 123,00 (entrada 123) o programa tem o seguinte resultado:

```
  Digite o valor a pagar: 123
  2 cédula(s) de R$50
  1 cédula(s) de R$20
  0 cédula(s) de R$10
  0 cédula(s) de R$5
  3 cédula(s) de R$1
```

O que está acontecendo:

```
valor=int(input("Digite o valor a pagar:"))
cédulas=0 # Armazena quantas cédulas da mesma nota a pessoa vai receber
atual=50 # Armazena qual é o valor da nota que está sendo recebida 
apagar=valor # armazena o valor restante que falta para ser recebido
while True: # Roda o programa para "sempre" (enquanto o valor a receber não for 0,00)
    if atual<=apagar: # Se o valor da nota atual for menor que o valor restante a ser recebido 
        apagar-=atual # Subtrai o valor atual menos o valor da nota que será entregue
        cédulas+=1 # Conta quantas notas iguais a pessoa receberá
    else: #se não troca a nota por uma de valor menor
        print("%d cédula(s) de R$%d" % (cédulas, atual))
        if apagar == 0: # Se o valor a receber for 0,00 sai do loop e encerra o programa
            break
        if atual == 50: # Troca a nota por uma de valor menor 
            atual = 20
        elif atual == 20: # Troca a nota por uma de valor menor 
            atual = 10
        elif atual == 10: # Troca a nota por uma de valor menor 
            atual = 5
        elif atual == 5: # Troca a nota por uma de valor menor 
            atual = 1
        cédulas = 0
```

Basicamente o que está acontecendo é:

1. Ele verifica se a nota atual tem o valor menor que o total a pagar:

   `if atual<=apagar:`
2. Se for menor subtrai o valor da nota do valor total:

   `apagar-=atual cédulas+=1`
3. se for maior, ele troca a nota pela nota seguinte de valor menor:

`if atual == 50: atual = 20 elif atual == 20:  atual = 10 elif atual == 10:  atual = 5 elif atual == 5: atual = 1`

4. ele repete isso até zerar.