# Como fazer uma função atualizar os valores de uma variável?

Tags: python, funções, variáveis

Olá! Eu estou tentado fazer o exercício 1018 do BeeCrowd, onde você recebe um valor em reais e tem que distribuí-lo em notas de 100, 50, 25, 10, 5, 2 e 1 (por exemplo, 200 = 2 notas de 100). Para não ser repetitivo tentei implementar tudo em uma função, no entanto ela não atualiza o valor da minha variável. Tem como fazer algo parecido em python?

```
def troco(valor, notas_em_x):
    notas = valor//notas_em_x
    valor %= notas_em_x
    return notas


valor = int(input())

print(valor)

print(f"""{troco(valor, 100)} nota(s) de R$ 100,00
{troco(valor, 50)} nota(s) de R$ 50,00
{troco(valor, 25)} nota(s) de R$ 25,00
{troco(valor, 10)} nota(s) R$ 10,00
{troco(valor, 5)} nota(s) de R$ 5,00
{troco(valor, 2)} nota(s) de R$ 2,00
{troco(valor, 1)} nota(s) de R$ 1,00""")
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como mudar o valor de uma variável por meio de função no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/226738/como-mudar-o-valor-de-uma-vari%c3%a1vel-por-meio-de-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-no-python)

Comment: Vc está tentando resolver o problema errado. A melhor solução para não ser repetitivo não é essa função, e sim um loop simples, veja: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/467069/112052 - com isso vc elimina os problemas que não precisariam existir (e assim pode até ignorar as respostas abaixo, que focam no problema errado - nada de usar `global` nem nada do tipo, pois o problema não é modificar o valor dentro da função, já que essa função não é a melhor solução).

Comment: Mas se quiser muito usar essa função, basta modificá-la para retornar o valor atualizado. E aí vc usa ela em um loop - **vale notar que o loop é o principal meio de evitar a repetição**, pois a verdadeira repetição no seu código é chamar a função várias vezes. Seria algo assim: https://ideone.com/lAN50h - ou seja, nada de global nem nenhuma outra gambiarra sugerida nas respostas abaixo

Answer (score -2):

Olá, Todas as variável em Python possuem um escopo, onde a mesma só pode ser utilizada nele.
Neste caso é possível atualizar o valor da variável declarando ela como uma variável de escopo global, não
é necessário informar o valor da variável para cada chamada da função.

```
def troco(notas_em_x):
   global valor
   notas =valor//notas_em_x 
   valor %= notas_em_x
   return notas


valor = int(input())

print(valor)

print(f'''{troco(100)} nota(s) de R$ 100,00
{troco(50)} nota(s) de R$ 50,00
{troco(25)} nota(s) de R$ 25,00
{troco(10)} nota(s) R$ 10,00
{troco(5)} nota(s) de R$ 5,00
{troco(2)} nota(s) de R$ 2,00
{troco(1)} nota(s) de R$ 1,00''')
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/925/112052